# limit for access tokens

Tags: api, refresh, token, limit

I'm creating a app that uses Giigle Drive API.
The Google's document says that there is a **limit for access tokens** issued per client-user combination.
It is said 15, 20, 50.(I don't know exact number)

But in my case, the limit of number seems to be just one.

I installed my app to several Android machines.
**The first machine can get access-token and refresh-token at one time.**
But in case of the second one and after, **only access-token** can be acquired.
i.e. no refresh-token.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem  or increase the number?

## ==============================================

Sep.13 2017

Thank you very much "Tanaike" for the kind advice. My explanation was not good. (because I'm not native English speaker.)

Anyway, let me explain again.

Here I have three android phones, #A , #B , #C. And I installed my app to all of them.

At first, #A sends request for the access token to Google. Then I allow the request for my Google account GGG@gmail.com Then #A can get access token and refresh token.

Next, #B tries the same thing to the same account GGG@gmail.com. Then #B can get access token but no refresh token.

And next, #C tries the same thing. Then #C can get access token but no refresh token.

In such a situation, #A can get another access token before it is expired. But #B and #C cannot get new access token. They only have to wait when the access token is expired.

That I would have liked to write.

Regards,

==============================================

Sep.18 2017

Thank you "Tanaike".
I've not been able to touch this subject for a while, sorry.
I've tried "access_type=offline" .....
but in fact, I've found that I had already included "access_type=offline" from the first time.

So that mean, after #A gets refresh-token, #B , #C and later machines cannot get refresh-token
even though "access_type=offline".
This is a regrettable result.
I'd like to know the way how to provide refresh token to each device.

==============================================

Comment: For each device, can I ask you about the detail information of method for retrieving access token? What is the materials for retrieving access token?

Comment: If you couldn't understand my comments, feel free to tell me.

Comment: My process to require Access-token is this below.
----------------------------------------------------------
end point : https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
body
  code=(Auth code)
  grant_type=authorization_code
  client_id=(my app's client id)
  client_secret=(my app's client secret)
  redirect_uri=(path of the page in my domain)
----------------------------------------------------------

Comment: ^^^^^^   Oh sorry.  line feeds are remuved

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. When the "Auth code" is retrieved, is ``access_type=offline`` included in the URL? If the same auth code is used for each device, the error occurs. the use of auth code is only one time. As a next question, can I ask you about the flow for retrieving access token for each device?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. I didn't include "access_type=offline".   
I'll try it tomorrow.    
The flow for retrieving is #A => #B => #C in series.   
They send the same HTTP POST request.   
Regards  
Oh, It's time to go to bed. ('') Zzzzzzzz so sleepy.

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. My latest question is the flow for retrieving access token for the individual device. For example, 1. Retrieve client id and secret, 2. Retrieve auth code, 3. Retrieve refresh token, 4. Retrieve access token. If you want to use Japanese, feel free to mail me. You can see my e-mail address from GitHub on my profile.

Answer (score 0):

- When it retrieves the access token using refresh token, **the refresh token is not included in the response**.
- The refresh token retrieved by Google OAuth2 has **no expiration time**. So until you revoke the refresh token, you can continue to use it. The expiration time of access token is 3600 seconds.
- For example, it retrieves the access token using the refresh token "A". After this, the access token is retrieved using the refresh token "A" again, soon. By this, although you have 2 access tokens, the both access tokens can be used. It is possible to increase access tokens using one refresh token by repeating this. But I don't know whether this is the right way for Google users.

> But in case of the second one and after, only access-token can be acquired. i.e. no refresh-token.

You already have refresh token from your question. So you can retrieve access token using it. In your situation, if the refresh token is inside in each machine, they can retrieve access token using it.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.